# Querydsl SELECT something as something_else

Tags: java, sql, group-by, querydsl

Is it possible to write Querydsl equivalent of this SQL?

```
SELECT coalesce(m.MATERIAL_GROUP, sc.MATERIAL_ID) AS GROUP_ID FROM STOCK_CARD sc JOIN MATERIAL m ON (sc.MATERIAL_ID = m.ID) GROUP BY GROUP_ID;
```

In Querydsl I have tried (stockCard is statically imported):

```
public List<Long> justAnExample() {
    NumberPath<Long> group_id = Expressions.numberPath(Long.class, "group_id");
    return from(stockCard)
            .groupBy(group_id)
            .list(stockCard.material.materialGroup.id.coalesce(stockCard.material.id).as(group_id));
}
```

But it seems that Querydsl is ignoring "as()", because generated SQL is:

```
select coalesce(material1_.MATERIAL_GROUP, stockcard0_.MATERIAL_ID) as col_0_0_ from STOCK_CARD stockcard0_, MATERIAL material1_ where stockcard0_.MATERIAL_ID=material1_.id group by group_id
```

Please note that is just a very simplified query to try whether it is possible.
Thanks!

Comment: Are you using JPA by any chance?
This doesn't look like Querydsl output, but more like Hibernate.

Comment: I am using Hibernate and Spring data, my repository class extends QueryDslRepositorySupport.

Answer (score 0):

This might be related to this Hibernate bug https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-1902